# how to make a flip animation horizontal with CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

i made a blackjack game , i want to make the dealer cards flip from back to front everything works expect that when the shown cards appear they apper one under another .. how can i make them appear
in line ??

```js
function TurnDealerCards()
{
    DealerCards.innerHTML = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < DealerArray.length; i++) {
        var Dealercard = document.createElement('img');
        var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
        Dealercard.setAttribute("width", 50);
        Dealercard.setAttribute("src", (allCards[random])[(DealerArray[i])]);
        DealerCards.appendChild(Dealercard);
        
    }
    DealerCards.className = 'myDIV';
        

}
```

```css
.myDIV {
            display:inline-block;
            border: 0px;
            width: 50px;
            
            background-color:transparent;
            color: transparent;
            animation: mymove 1s ;
        }
        @keyframes mymove {
            50% {
                transform: rotateY(180deg);
               
            }
        }
```

```html
 <table border="0" width="100%" height="100%" style="text-align: center">
          <tr><th id="NewGame" onclick="MakeAnewGame();" style="float:left">
    <img src="media/cards/new game.png" width="100" /><label>change table color</label><input id="changeBGC" type="button" onclick="changeBackground();">
</th></tr>
            <tr><td style="height:100pt;width:100%;font-size:100pt;color:white"><div id="dealer"></div></td></tr>
```

Comment: You are setting the `myDIV` class on the outer `DealerCards` div, but the CSS looks like you want to apply it to each individual `Dealercard` instead.

Comment: if you want to set `inline` to outer div you have to use `display:flex`

Comment: Can you provide some markup

Comment: thanks lavni the display display:flex-inline works, . but it turns all the cards as 1 part  instead of flipping each card

Comment: it's a very very very long code this is the only part that refers to flipping .. still want me to add it?

Comment: 1. add only relevant code to make snippet works 2.  some note: in js  it in common to declare property with small letter as `var dealer` and not `var Dealer`

Comment: ok thank you :) , i added the relevant html part. the refered id is the last one , id = dealer

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:flex` to the wrap (`myDiv`) and use animation to each `img`

In **js** set `animation-delay` and increase the time one by one

```js
var DealerCards=document.getElementById("cards");
DealerCards.innerHTML = "";
var DealerArray=[1,1,1];
    for (var i = 0; i < DealerArray.length; i++) {

        var Dealercard = document.createElement('img');
        var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
        Dealercard.setAttribute("width", 50);
        Dealercard.setAttribute("src","jj");
Dealercard.style.animationDelay=(i + 0.5 )+'s';
        DealerCards.appendChild(Dealercard);
       
    }
    DealerCards.className = 'myDIV';
```

```css
.myDIV img{
 
            border: 0px;
            width: 50px;
            animation: mymove 1s;
            background-color:transparent;
            color: transparent;
        }
myDiv {
display:flex;
}
        @keyframes mymove {
            50% {
                transform: rotateY(180deg);
               
            }
        }
```

```html
<div id="cards"></div>
```

Comment: can you explain please?

Comment: yes , it works but it flips all the pics at once not one by one

Comment: the class name is outside the for loop is different?, i changed it and still flips all in once

Comment: function TurnDealerCards()
{
    DealerCards.innerHTML = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < DealerArray.length; i++) {
        var Dealercard = document.createElement('img');
        var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
        Dealercard.setAttribute("width", 50);
        Dealercard.setAttribute("src", (allCards[random])[(DealerArray[i])]);
        Dealercard.style.animationDelay = (i + 0.5) + 's';
        DealerCards.appendChild(Dealercard);
        
    }
    DealerCards.className = 'myDIV';
        

}

Comment: it flips horiznatly yes , but i wanted the cards to flip one by one and not all as 1 part it's like all the cards are the same image .. if there's not a way to fix it thank you very much anyways :):)

Comment: i copied the same code , just changed the relevant names  and doesnt work , what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233835/discussion-between-avihu24-and--).